# Let $\partial E$, be the boundary of $E \subset \Bbb R^n$. Show that if $m^*(\partial E)=0$, then $E$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $\partial E$, be the boundary of $E \subset \Bbb R^n$. Show that if $m^*(\partial E)=0$, then $E$ is measurable.

I've posted this previously, but had couple of questions regarding my attempt.

Let $B \subset \partial E$ such that $E= \operatorname{int(E)} \cup B$. Now $\operatorname{int(E)}$ is measurable as it is an open set so we need to show that $B$ is measurable in order to conclude that $E$ is e.g we need to prove that subsets of sets with measure zero are measurable.

In order for $B$ to be measurable it has to satisfy $$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \setminus B)$$ for all $A \subset \Bbb R^n$.

Now since $A \cap B \subset \partial E$ and by the monotonicity of the outer measure we have that $m^*(A\cap B) \le m^*(\partial E) =0$ and similarly $m^*(A \setminus B) \le m^*(\partial E) =0$ but this would mean that $$m^*(A) = 0$$ since the measure cannot be negative? Is there something fundamentally wrong here? Is it true that $$A \cap B \subset \partial E$$ and $$A \setminus B \subset \partial E$$ if $B \subset \partial E$?

Comment: The set $E \setminus \partial E$ is open. Does that help?

Comment: What is $m^*{}$?

Comment: $A\setminus B \subset \partial E$ is certainly wrong.

Comment: you are trying to check that a subset of a set of measure $0$ is measurable. You only need to check LHS $\ge$ RHS, it's simple if you are a bit careful.

Comment: @tomasz It's the outer measure

Comment: @Danlo: Yes, but which one? Lebesgue? You should specify that in your question.